# What does it mean to "sniff at someone?"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The book series "The Wheel of Time" frequently talks about characters "sniffing" at someone.

Here are a few examples:

> “ ‘Poke the meekest dog too often,’ “ Elayne quoted, “ ‘and he will bite.’ Not that Lan is very meek.” She got a sharp look and a sniff from Nynaeve.

Or this one:

> Her smile became a grin that made Elayne sniff disapprovingly

It doesn't seem natural to think of someone inhaling air through their nose in these situations... So what does it really mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sniff (*drawing air through the nose in a short, audible inhalation*) is sometimes used as a sign of contempt.  See [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sniff?s=t):

> **4.** to show disdain, contempt, etc., by or as by sniffing.

Nynaeve is disparaging Elayne's comment by the sniff.  Note that a sniff can be a haughty way to express disdain, as if words would be too much to waste.

Comment: +1. Good answer. Interestingly, when you sniff at someone in disdain I think you actually *exhale* air in a small burst through your nose. Try it.

Comment: I think it works either way :)

Comment: @JLG, no, that would be a derisive snort, not a sniff.  I prefer to sniff, as it reduces the risk of making a mess.

Comment: :) I snorted with laughter then, but daintily.

Comment: This is a good answer, and is as expected... the problem I find is that it seems unnatural. As you talk you exhale. Are you really going to stop talking/exhaling just to then sharply inhale? It just  doesn't seem to flow well. Likewise, as I'm reading these novels, I find it strange to imagine the characters "inhaling" anytime they sniff at someone.

Comment: Perhaps you're not used to people sniffing, then.  They do it, nevertheless.